Detect EntityState of ALL included entities in Entity Framework query
I have a Linq query which returns related data with the .Include() method from Entity Framework (see below). My question is how would I get the EntityState of both the Companies and Addresses from this single query?
Dim updatedCompany As Company = 
    DAL.Companies
       .Include("Addresses")
       .ToList
       .Where(Function(c) c.EntityState = EntityState.Modified)
       .FirstOrDefault()

I did split the query into two, detecting the EntityState of Addresses changes and querying the related Companies entry separately. However, this is less than ideal.
If it is not possible, so be it. That said, we have queries with more than one Includes function that may become an issue in the future.
FYI, the application is written in VB.NET, and is using EF version 6.4.0. This app is on "life support" while a replacement is being developed, so upgrading and/or changing the stack is unfortunately not an option.

First off, I'd use context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>() to find already attached entities only. Entities that are pulled freshly from the database are never Modified. (I.e. context.ChangeTracker.Entries(Of T)())
